# Weird return of data after splice and setstate

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Here's simulate in codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/embed/epic-nash-mxteu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I am having a weird behavior when I remove a row from the dynamic rows created.

I have removed the row with **2 b**. As you can see the console log has the correct data while the UI showing wrong data. It means the function works well but somehow displaying incorrectly.

Anyone have idea why? Thanks in advance

**Screenshots**

Before remove row

[image]

After remove row

[image]

**Source code**

```
const [gavRows, setGAVRows] = useState([]);

const handleGAVAddRow = async () => {
    try {
        const item = {
            gav_field: '',
            gav_value: ''
        };
        setGAVRows([...gavRows, item]);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error)
    }
};

const handleGAVRemoveSpecificRow = (idx) => {
    console.log('idx', idx)
    const tempRows = [...gavRows];
    console.log('tempRows', tempRows)
    tempRows.splice(idx, 1);
    setGAVRows(tempRows)
};


const handleGAVChange = async (idx, e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    var tempRows = [...gavRows];
    tempRows[idx][name] = value;

    setGAVRows(tempRows)
};


<table className="customgav_section">
    <tbody>
        {
            gavRows.map((item, idx) => {
                console.log('map idx', idx, item)
                return (
                    <tr key={idx}>
                        <td>
                            <Input type="text"
                                name="gav_field" id="gav_field"
                                value={gavRows[idx].field}
                                onChange={(e) => handleGAVChange(idx, e)}
                            />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <Input type="text"
                                name="gav_value" id="gav_value"
                                value={gavRows[idx].value}
                                onChange={(e) => handleGAVChange(idx, e)}
                            />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <Button outline color="danger" onClick={() => handleGAVRemoveSpecificRow(idx)}><FaMinus /></Button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>)
            })
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: do you prefer to provide stackblitz or codesandbox code?

Comment: hi, here's the link to codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/embed/epic-nash-mxteu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark please add row to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-grass-n303z?file=/src/App.tsx)

The problem is you put the wrong input value.

Remember the item object you set is:

```
const item = {
  gav_field: "", //not field
  gav_value: ""  //not value
};
```

You should modify code from

```
<td>
   <Input
     type="text"
     name="gav_field"
     id="gav_field"
     value={gavRows[idx].field}
     onChange={(e) => handleGAVChange(idx, e)}
   />
</td>
<td>
   <Input
      type="text"
      name="gav_value"
      id="gav_value"
      value={gavRows[idx].value}
      onChange={(e) => handleGAVChange(idx, e)}
   />
</td>
```

To:

```
<td>
   <Input
     type="text"
     name="gav_field"
     id="gav_field"
     value={gavRows[idx].gav_field}
     onChange={(e) => handleGAVChange(idx, e)}
   />
</td>
<td>
   <Input
      type="text"
      name="gav_value"
      id="gav_value"
      value={gavRows[idx].gav_value}
      onChange={(e) => handleGAVChange(idx, e)}
   />
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are using the index of the array as the key.

Read why that is bad: https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

A quick hack was assigning a random number as the key of each item in the `gavRows` and using that as the key of the element. See updated code: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-bouman-03zn7

Also, the `id` of an element must be unique in the DOM so i removed those from the `input` elements.